# yarn warning package has unmet react peer dependency

Tags: package.json, yarnpkg

I am getting a whole heap of unmet peer-dependency warnings when doing a fresh install with `yarn`.

I own one of the dependencies (lets call it `my-problematic-package`) and have set the peerDependency as follows:

```
"peerDependencies": {
  "react": "0.14.x - 16.x.x",
  "react-dom": "0.14.x - 16.x.x"
}
```

I am then including the package in my project with the following defined for dependencies:

```
"dependencies": {
  ...
  "react: "^16.0.0",
  "my-problematic-package": "^1.1.0" // Latest with react as devDependency
}
```

I then get the following when running `yarn`:

```
warning > my-problematic-package@1.1.0" has unmet peer dependency "react@0.14.x - 16.x.x".
```

Seems legit but not working, any suggestions welcome.

Yarn version: **1.3.2**

NPM version: **5.5.1**

Comment: Looks like this could be related to this issue: https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/4850

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Okay, so it turns out it was not my problem. Yarn v 1.3.2 has a bug when warning on `peerDependencies`.

`1.4.0` shipped as a release candidate a couple of days ago and I no longer see these incorrect warnings in this release.

Links:
Related issue: https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/4743
PR: https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/pull/5088